# What is the equivalent of MySQL @currant := @currank + 1 in MS SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

This is the main MySQL script I try to convert this following script into MS SQL script. I don't know the equivalent.

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT 
                COALESCE(transaction_price, 0)
            FROM
                (SELECT 
                    COALESCE(transaction_price, 0) AS TRANSACTION_PRICE, COALESCE(actual_size, 0) AS ACTUAL_SIZE, @currank = @currank + 1 AS rank
                FROM
                    dw_property_detail p, (SELECT @currank:=0) r
                WHERE
                    land_id = 2 AND transaction_price IS NOT NULL AND flat_type = 'Studio'
                ORDER BY transaction_price DESC) x
            WHERE
                x.rank = 1) AS TRAN_S, 
        (SELECT 
                COALESCE(per_ft_s, 0)
            FROM
                (SELECT 
                    COALESCE(transaction_price / actual_size, 0) AS PER_FT_S, @currank:=@currank + 1 AS rank
                FROM
                    dw_property_detail p, (SELECT @currank:=0) r
                WHERE
                    land_id = 2 AND transaction_price IS NOT NULL AND flat_type = 'Studio'
                ORDER BY COALESCE(transaction_price / actual_size, 0) DESC) x
            WHERE
                x.rank = 1) AS PER_FT_S
```

What is the equivalent of `@currank := @currank + 1` and `SELECT @currank := 0`?

Comment: What is this query supposed to do? Can you share some sample data and the result the query produces?

Comment: Ok I will update the MySQL query. Please see.

Answer (score 1):

ROW_NUMBER  (window/analytic function - feature that currently is not supported by MySQL)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Add it to the SELECT clause as an additional column.
You won't need now the query's ORDER BY, for that purpose (but do keep it if you want ordered results)

```
row_number() over (order by transaction_price desc)
```

---

```
SELECT      COALESCE(transaction_price, 0)                          AS TRANSACTION_PRICE
           ,COALESCE(actual_size, 0)                                AS ACTUAL_SIZE
           ,row_number () over (order by transaction_price DESC)    AS rank

FROM        dw_property_detail p

WHERE       land_id     = 2 
        AND flat_type   = 'Studio'
        AND transaction_price IS NOT NULL 

ORDER BY    transaction_price DESC
```

Comment: Can you do me sample I get lost. I don't understand. :P

Comment: Check the examples at the bottom of the added link

Comment: can you simplify my script?

Comment: oops, it only return 2 column TRAN_S and PER_FT_S but yours is return 3 column transaction_price, actual_price, and rank

Comment: It is just the sub-query part, not the whole query

Comment: I don't understand. Honestly, I am a newly in TSQL. Can you update the whole?